# Possible null reference argument while adding an item to a list

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following code to read columns from SQL table:

```
public List<string> GetColumns(string tableName)
{
   var columns = new List<string>();          
   using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SqlServerConnectionString))
   {
      conn.Open();
      var selectQuery = $"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{tableName}'";
      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
      {
           using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {                 
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    columns.Add(reader["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
                }
           }                            
      }                   
      conn.Close();
   }
   return columns;
}
```

I see this warning on running the code:

> Possible null reference argument for parameter 'item' in 'void List.Add(string item)'

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `reader[...]` returns `Object`, and `Object` defines `ToString` as returning `String?`. Use `GetString` instead.

Comment: why is tablename  not a parameter, and where was it set

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null warning probably warns you that reader["COLUMNAME"] might returns null. Even tho it in praxis should not occur, your compiler would never know.
May just add a variable for the reader["COLUMNAME"] and check if it's null before adding it to the list.

I'm not sure why it won't mention that .ToString() call but the List.Add.

Edit: and what was said in the comments of your question: better use SqlParameters instead of directly using strings in the query to avoid SQL injections.